# instantiate classes from other projects

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have MyClassA in project a.

```
package com.testa

public class MyClassA {

    private Data data;

    public data setData() {
        this.data = data;

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Data is an interface declared in project a.

In project b I have SpecialData like:

```
package com.testb

public class SpecialData extends Data {
   // ...
}
```

Project b depends on a, but not the other way round, so MyClassA can not instantiate SpecialData directly.

I would like to refactor MyClassA to get rid of the setter and instatiate the correct data lazy like:

```
    public Data getData() {
        if (data != null) {
            return data;
        }
        if (projectB.isEnabled) {
            return //somehow SpecialData
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

Is there any way to do so? Any design pattern I am missing?

Comment: Pass the Data to the constructor, not a setter.  (Why do you have setters anyway?  Most things should be immutable.)

Comment: Maybe `MyClassA`'s `data` field should be generic? edit: and require the generic parameter to extend `Data`

Comment: If you want `MyClassA` to create a `SpecialData`, you might need to pass it a class/factory that makes the type of data you want it to have.  `public class DataFactory { public Data makeNew() { return new SpecialData()} }`

Comment: Even if I pass it to the constructor within project a, I have the same problem, no?

Comment: How would that work with a DataFactory? Unfortunately I am not getting it...

Comment: `public class SpecialData extends Data` - is `Data` really an interface?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Without knowing more details about your classes: In your refactored code, `getData` could be a pain to test (or to have called in any test), if that data is anything non-trivial with dependencies on its own. If you need getters and setters, you may want to check [Tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html). Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write in project A something like:

```
if (projectB.isEnabled)
```

because project A does not know anything about project B.

However, you can do something close to what you want using dependency injection, I will show it with Spring Boot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nuggit</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecta</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projecta</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>    
</project>
```

And the classes you used (I added a method), MyClassA:

```
package com.nuggit.projecta;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyClassA {

    private Data data;

    public MyClassA(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int execute(int value) {
        return data.doData(value);
    }
}
```

The Data interface:

```
package com.nuggit.projecta;

public interface Data {

    int doData(int value);
}
```

Now you can install this maven project and add it as a dependency in project B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nuggit</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectb</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nuggit</groupId>
            <artifactId>projecta</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Project B can define SpecialData:

```
package com.nuggit.projectb;


import com.nuggit.projecta.Data;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpecialData implements Data {
    @Override
    public int doData(int value) {
        return value / 2;
    }
}
```

And it will automatically get picked up because it is the only bean that implements the Data interface:

```
package com.nuggit.projectb;

import com.nuggit.projecta.MyClassA;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.nuggit"})
public class ProjectbApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectbApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyClassA myClassA;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
            LOG.info("Result {}", myClassA.execute(42));
    }
}
```

This works, and gives the output:

```
2024-03-12T22:46:12.906+01:00  INFO 17008 --- [projectb] [           main] c.nuggit.projectb.ProjectbApplication    : Started ProjectbApplication in 0.817 seconds (process running for 1.309)
2024-03-12T22:46:12.909+01:00  INFO 17008 --- [projectb] [           main] c.nuggit.projectb.ProjectbApplication    : Result 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using generics:

```
public class MyClassA<T extends Data> {  // limit the generic type
    private final T data;  // make it immutable

    public MyClassA(T data) { // add constructor
       this.data = data;
    }

    // return generic type
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

then for usage:

```
var withBasicData = new MyClassA<>(new Data());
var withSpecialData = new MyClassA<>(new SpecialData());

// compilation error as expected since the generic type is limited
var withSomethingElse = new MyClassA<>(Integer.valueOf(42));
```